# Оценка кода PHP

Tags: php

Насколько хорош этот кусок кода? если он вам не нравится что бы вы изменили?

```
        <h3 class="margin-top-minus-10 font-24"><span class="tour-icon"></span>Tours To Uzbekistan</h3>

        <?php $current_tour_category = FALSE; ?>

        <?php foreach ($tours as $tour) : ?>

            <?php if ($tour['tour_category_name'] != $current_tour_category) : ?> 
                <?php $current_tour_category = $tour['tour_category_name']; ?>
                <div class="middle-seperator"></div>>
                <h5 class="tour-category-name"><?=$tour['tour_category_name']?></h5>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <!-- TOUR ITEM START -->
            <div class="tour-item in-category">
                <?php if ( ! empty($tour['picture']) AND file_exists('uploads/tours/'.$tour['picture'])) : ?>
                    <img src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/tours/<?=$tour['picture']?>" alt="" />
                <?php else : ?>
                    <img src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/no-picture.jpg" alt="" />
                <?php endif; ?>
                <h5><?=$tour['name']?></h5>
                <?php if ( ! empty($tour['quote'])) : ?>
                    <blockquote><?=$tour['quote']?></blockquote>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <blockquote><?=character_limiter(strip_tags($tour['text']), 150)?></blockquote>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <div class="tour-item-footer"> 
                    <div class="days"><?=lang('days')?> <?=$tour['days']?></div>
                    <div class="nights"><?=lang('nights')?> <?=$tour['nights']?></div>
                    <div class="reviews"><a href="#"><?=lang('reviews')?>: <?=$tour['reviews_count']?></a></div>
                    <div class="pdf"><a href="<?=base_url()?>uploads/tours/pdf/<?=$tour['pdf']?>"><?=lang('download_in_pdf')?></a></div>
                </div><!-- .tour-item-footer -->
                <div class="costs"><span><?=lang('from')?></span> $<?=$tour['price']?></div>
            </div><!-- .tour-item -->
            <!-- TOUR ITEM END -->

        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: @Palmervan, на будущее - удалять достаточно **свои** комментарии. Удалять чужие - плохая практика.

Comment: Обычная вьюха. что тут менять?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы использовал шаблонизатор, потому что от мешанины html и php у меня глаза слезятся. Я не говорю про мультикомбайны типа Smarty - нет, что-нибудь простое, позволяющее отделить логику от представления. Я для этого использую свой простенький шаблонизатор и доволен как слон.

Comment: Как синий слон? :)

А где там логика-то? я вижу один цикл и три if/else) Не, тут я возникать не буду, по крайней мере практическая польза есть.

*Че-то я до всех второй день докапываюсь как-то агрессивно. Пардоньте, оно само ._.*

Comment: Логику от представления отделяет программист а не шаблонизатор.

Если речь о PHP - не вижу смысла писать лишнюю магию поверх нативной реализации, PHP уже обладает всеми необходимыми свойствами шаблонизатора.

В хорошем коде шаблона мешанины практически нет, а если и есть нагруженые кодом места - они красиво отеделены и подробно закоментированы.

И тут не важно - шаблон с использованием шаблонизатора или без, проблему наплевательского отношения и отсутствия мозгов это не решет =)

PS: все выше изложеное всеголишь скромное ИМХО

Comment: @Sh4dow, по мне, логика - это все, что не начинается на `<?=`. Цикл и три условия тоже не способствуют пониманию шаблона.  
@AlexWindHope, я сказал: "установите шаблонизатор - он сам все отделит"? Пардон, не хотел вводить в заблуждение. =) А вообще, я отвечал на вопрос "что бы я улучшил". Так вот: я бы убрал управляющие конструкции из шаблона, чтобы сделать его нагляднее. Вот и все. =)

Comment: @ling - выглядит действительно примерно так =)

Answer (score 1):

Прошлый век :) Не люблю когда генерация HTML происходит с помощью PHP.
Вот если бы у тя PHP генерил JSON-ы, а JS генерировал на основе них код -было бы супер :)

Comment: А на счет производительности? я думаю времени больше уйдет )

Comment: Ну если так использует около 70%-80% программистов PHP ну и Smarty там

Comment: Кроме гугла этой ереси нигде не видел. Генерить хтмл на клиенте - адъ и погiбель. Хоть один аргумент в защиту такой практики?

Против:

 - производительность на клиенте (браузер не может рендерить "на лету" и распределять нагрузку)
 - невозможность кэширования готового кода
 - извраты с экранированием
 - трудность редактирования

@FreelancerUz если вы не в большой компании с полным разделением кода и хтмл - не пользуйтесь смарти. В нем просто нет смысла.

Comment: @Sh4dow вполне свами согласен! По мне Smarty это как излишество которая проста жрет память и скорость работы скрипта а в замен? а ну да трата времени

Comment: @Sh4dow, почему нет смысла в смарти? вот сайт www.servershop.pro сделал на смарти...

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай, смысл есть при четком разделении труда + уже **есть** верстальщик, знающий смарти. В любом другом случае это бессмысленная замена native php. У меня в вопросах [есть](http://hashcode.ru/questions/23630/) обсуждение, и это единственный найденный сообществом смысл)

Comment: ВКонтакт имеет ту же политику формирования страницы.Кстати, весьма весомый аргумент:нагрузка -80%

- производительность на клиенте (браузер не может рендерить "на лету" и распределять нагрузку)

да ладно ? Взять тот же QOOXDOO, либо ExtJS. Они прекрасно умеют работать на клиенте и у них прекрасная производительность :) 

 - невозможность кэширования готового кода
  
 Да ладно :) А что мешает кэшировать данные, из которых будет лепиться JSON ?

 - извраты с экранированием

Оп, какие ? 

 - трудность редактирования
Фигассе. Никаких. Неужели проблема из массива, либо объекта сделать JSON ?

Comment: - надо сперва дождаться всех данных, а потом рендерить. оптимизация браузера умножена на ноль. Вы сперва кодом собираете данные, потом кодом парсите их, потом кодом составляете документ и только потом он рендерится.
 - кэшировать данные ничего не мешает, а кэшировать готовый исполненный файл - нельзя
 - всякие, с inline-js в частности. Не сталкивались?)
 - из какого массива? редактировать шаблон труднее. И тут вам уже никакой верстальщик не поможет

Так аргументы в пользу будут, кроме того, что "это круто и стильно"? Кстати, вот не уверен, но имхо поисковикам это тоже не понравится.

Comment: @Sh4dowm - опыт работы и знание матчасти в этом вопросе ~= 0.
Я не буду писать что это лучшее решение, но по поводу "минусов"

 - Зато можно асинхронно тянуть данные для отрисовки всей страницы по частям

 - кэшировать готовый исполненный файл - нельзя? Ниче что JSники, если не изменились, подымаються с кеша? Да и шаблоны тоже кешируются браузером.

 - без комментариев, просто глупость

 - Редактировать шаблон труднее? Не труднее чем Smarty или native php шаблон, или ты думаешь что рендеринг происходит контактацией строк?
Про верстальщика - бред полный.

 - С последним, правда, спорить не буд

Comment: Вообще для обычного сайта компании либо домашней странички Васи Пупкина это, естественно, не нужно. Никто не говорит что этого сделать нельзя, просто выиграш ~= 0.

В большей степени это подходит для RIA приложений, либо для сайтов с *сексуальным* удобным UI и кучей плюшек.

Кстати - из неочевидного плюса, если сервер общаеться исключительно JSON'ом намного проще писать приложение под моб устройства т.к. нет необходимости переписывать сервер, но это, конечно-же, особенность специфическая.